# findViewById on an ImageView why does setBackgroundColor give NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview

I have a very basic activity with an ImageView of android:id="@+id/imageViewTest"
and then in the OnCreate method calling:

```
ImageView imageView =  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewTest);
    // Set the background color to white
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

this gives error:

```
    10-15 16:36:27.552  29097-29097/org.explore.self.beginner D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
10-15 16:36:28.017  29097-29097/org.explore.self.beginner D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-15 16:36:28.017  29097-29097/org.explore.self.beginner W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d9b2a0)
10-15 16:36:28.042  29097-29097/org.explore.self.beginner E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.explore.self.beginner/org.selfexplore.android.view.activity.TestActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.selfexplore.android.view.activity.TestActivity.onCreate(TestActivity.java:37)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 16:36:28.062  29097-29097/org.explore.self.beginner I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 29097 SIG: 9
```

But when I do a

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
```

it works fine, Why?

PS: I am not able to add the layout code here, so sharing it in this doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fbi3B_hAYUh_C2IwPfInvZ-BG2bgsa4pZoJKj8NBT9o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you please post your activity code as well as layout ?

Comment: Can you post your Activity's onCreate block? Are you calling setContentView(R.layout.whatever)?

Comment: I had posted the activity layout XML but StockOverflow was saying too much code and not allowing to post, so I had to remove... here it is:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout you've set with `setContentView()` doesn't have a view with id `imageViewTest` and `findViewById()` returns `null`, or you haven't called `setContentView()` at all.

Comment: thanks for the help... I had copied the code and forgot to add the line, setContentView(R.layout.activity_test); Added that and it fixed it.